# 0xc0000225 error when trying to install windows from USB stick

Tags: hard-drive, usb, bootloader, windows-installation, bootable-media

I have an old Dell laptop with windows 7. 1 week ago, while i was doing some work, it accidentaly fell on the floor. The laptop was super laggy and after a while it would show bluescreen. This happened to my old Lenovo thinkpad too. I replaced the hard drive and now it works fine. I bought new a hard drive for my dell too. After i replaced it, i created a windows 7 installation USB.But i couldn't install it! I got this error.

[image]

I tried installing windows 8 and i got the same error.
I tried extracting the **.wim** to the hard drive using **gimagex.exe** but that didn't work too. The cursor just keep flashing and it wouldn't boot.

Comment: Are you sure you are booting from the USB? Are you certain the boot media suits the computer? Give more details.

Comment: @harrymc what do you mean "the boot media suits the computer"? Yes i am booting from the USB

Comment: For example, booting a 32-bit Windows version for a 32-bit computer.

Comment: @harrymc The laptop has a 64bit processor

Comment: Enter the Dell bios and run the memory and hard drive diagnostics.

Comment: How did you prepare the USB?

Comment: @Moab I already did this. I didn't get any errors.

Comment: @gronostaj https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9585/how-to-setup-a-usb-flash-drive-to-install-windows-7/